DD/MM/YYYY format with MUI DatePicker and react-hook-form
I've written this datePicker component to integrate react-hook-form and Material UI, but i get, as an example, values formatted like this: "2024-04-10T22:00:00.000Z"
this is the code:
import { LocalizationProvider } from "@mui/x-date-pickers/LocalizationProvider";
import { DatePicker } from "@mui/x-date-pickers/DatePicker";
import { Control, Controller } from "react-hook-form";
import { FormType } from "./Context";
import { AdapterDayjs } from "@mui/x-date-pickers/AdapterDayjs";

type FormInputProps = {
    name: any;
    control: Control<FormType, any>;
    label: string;
};

export const FormDatePicker = ({ name, control, label }: FormInputProps) => {
    return (
        <LocalizationProvider dateAdapter={AdapterDayjs}>
            <Controller
                name={name}
                control={control}
                render={({ field: { onChange, value } }) => (
                    <DatePicker
                        slotProps={{
                            field: { clearable: true },
                        }}
                        label={label}
                        value={value}
                        format="DD/MM/YYYY"
                        onChange={onChange}
                    />
                )}
            />
        </LocalizationProvider>
    );
};


How can i make it so that values are stored in the string format of DD/MM/YYYY?

to ensure that the values stored in your form are in the string format of DD/MM/YYYY, you'll need to format the selected date before passing it to react-hook-form's onChange handler you can try the following :
import { LocalizationProvider } from "@mui/x-date-pickers/LocalizationProvider";
import { DatePicker } from "@mui/x-date-pickers/DatePicker";
import { Control, Controller } from "react-hook-form";
import { FormType } from "./Context";
import { AdapterDayjs } from "@mui/x-date-pickers/AdapterDayjs";
import dayjs from "dayjs"; // Import dayjs for date formatting

type FormInputProps = {
    name: any;
    control: Control<FormType, any>;
    label: string;
};

export const FormDatePicker = ({ name, control, label }: FormInputProps) => {
    return (
        <LocalizationProvider dateAdapter={AdapterDayjs}>
            <Controller
                name={name}
                control={control}
                render={({ field: { onChange, value } }) => (
                    <DatePicker
                        slotProps={{
                            field: { clearable: true },
                        }}
                        label={label}
                        value={value}
                        format="DD/MM/YYYY"
                        onChange={(date) => {
                            // Convert selected date to the desired format
                            const formattedDate = dayjs(date).format("DD/MM/YYYY");
                            // Pass the formatted date to react-hook-form's onChange
                            onChange(formattedDate);
                        }}
                    />
                )}
            />
        </LocalizationProvider>
    );
};


i've just tried it but i get 10 errors in the console saying "Warning: Failed prop type: Invalid prop value of type string supplied to ForwardRef(DatePicker2), expected object.", "Warning: Failed prop type: Invalid prop value of type string supplied to ForwardRef(DesktopDatePicker2), expected object.", "Uncaught TypeError: value.isValid is not a function isValid AdapterDayjs.js:352", "The above error occurred in the <ForwardRef(DesktopDatePicker2)> component:"

It seems the date format conversion caused errors. We need to ensure the value passed matches the object type expected by DatePicker.
